# How to put a char into a empty pointer of a string in pure C

Tags: c

I want to store a single char into a char array pointer and that action is in a while loop, adding in a new char every time. I *strictly* want to be into a variable and not printed because I am going to compare the text. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
     char c;
     char *string;

     while((c=getchar())!= EOF) //gets the next char in stdin and checks if stdin is not EOF.
     { 
        char temp[2];  // I was trying to convert c, a char to temp, a const char so that I can use strcat to concernate them to string but printf returns nothing.
        temp[0]=c;  //assigns temp
        temp[1]='\0';  //null end point
        strcat(string,temp);  //concernates the strings 
    }

    printf(string);  //prints out the string.
    return 0;
}
```

I am using GCC on Debain (POSIX/UNIX operating system) and want to have windows compatability.

EDIT:

I notice some communication errors with what I actually intend to do so I will explain: I want to create a system where I can input a unlimited amount of characters and have the that input be store in a variable and read back from a variable to me, and to get around using realloc and malloc I made it so it would get the next available char until EOF. Keep in mind that I am a beginner to C (though most of you have probably guess it first) and haven't had a lot of experience memory management.

Comment: First of allo use `malloc` to allocate space of string...

Comment: @LPs: `malloc` to allocate a string of 2 bytes on the heap?

Comment: Read the manual for `strcat`. It says the receiving buffer needs to be of enough allocated space to receive the copy

Comment: @MOehm no, for the `char *string`. You are pointing somethong around the memory map. Your pointer is not initialized.

Comment: Whilst all the comments are correct in stating that you need to allocate memory for the string pointer, what's your actual question?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Why not declare `char string[2]` and assign it directly? Or, if you are dealing with single-letter strings throughout, just store them as `char` and compare them directly?

Comment: @LPs: I know that you mean the `char *string`, but allocating a buffer on the heap (and thus creating the memory management overhead) for something that needs two bytes is not a good advice, in my opinion.

Comment: You must **not** put a `char` into a pointer (you do not want to)! You might want, however store the value of a a `char` variable the pointer _points to_ (provided it is a _pointer to_ `char`. Or store the _address of_ a `char` variable into a pointer. For the example: the _pointer to_ `char` string points to no valid address. So you have to allocate memory first. Note also, that C does not have _strings_, but only _arrays of_ `char`. So it is your responsibility to provide enough free space in an array and have every _pointer to_ `char` pointing to valid memory space.

Comment: @MOehm: Agree for production code, but perhaps for a lesson? But that's all speculative, as the TO does not explain what he actually wants to achieve.

Comment: @MOehm, you could use an array, as someone else answered you, but you **have to** initialize your pointer.

Comment: @iharob: "pure C" would be a C-only compiler? (Not combined with a C++ compiler;-)

Comment: @Olaf, there is no such thing, c compilers and c++ compilers are very diffrent, it's not like Oh, lets make a c compiler complete by adding support for c++, c compilers compile c, c++ compilers compile c++, and c++ can compile code that a c compiler can compile but it'd still be c++.

Comment: @iharob: You really should debug your regex for emoticons  ;-) ;-) ;-) However, that is not (completely) true. For the parser, you are right, but the lexxer is basically the same, quite some optimizations can also be shared (between most languages, actually, see gcc and llvm, clang), symbol management mostly too, etc. Gues why llvm becomes more and more popular

Comment: The generated code is also different because the functions names are altered by the c++ compiler, but I see that you know that.

Comment: "... an unlimited ... store in a variable". That is impossible! Space is always limited,computer memory even more than space in universe.

Comment: @iharob: Well, I have done quite some research on compiler construction some years ago and I currently think about it just again for a reason (once I get some free time).

Comment: If you want to receive input *without any predefined limit* and store it in memory, then there is no alternative to dynamic allocation (`malloc()` / `calloc()`).  If you cannot determine before you start receiving the input how much there will be (i.e. on a run-by-run basis), then you must additionally be prepared to reallocate to obtain more space (`realloc()`).  There is no trick to get around this -- these functions are *the* way C provides for handling memory usage requirements such as you describe.

Comment: "unlimited amount of characters" - there is no such thing. As @JohnBollinger states, you surely mean *without any predefined limit* stored in memory. If you don't dynamically create a buffer to hold the characters, you can create a very large array on the stack, though this is not recommended and you should still check for input larger than your allocated array.

Comment: Use strncat instead of strcat if this is eventually going to become production code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want **unlimited** amount of character input, you'll need to actively manage the size of your buffer. Which is not as hard as it sounds.

- first use malloc to allocate, say, 1000 bytes.
- read until this runs out.
- use realloc to allocate 2000
- read until this runs out.

like this:

```
int main(){
  int buf_size=1000;
  char* buf=malloc(buf_size);
  char c;
  int n=0;
  while((c=getchar())!= EOF) 
     buf[n++] = c;
     if(n=>buf_size-1)
     {
        buf_size+=1000;
        buf=realloc(buf, buf_size);
     }
  }
  buf[n] = '\0'; //add trailing 0 at the end, to make it a proper string
  //do stuff with buf;
  free(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

You won't get around using malloc-oids if you want unlimited input.

Comment: what if realloc fails? Also: that would still be **limited**. The NSA is currently the only with **unlimited** space (apparently). ...

Comment: You have a point, but at least is better than `char buf[sizof(RAM)];`  ;)

Comment: as long as `sizeof(RAM) < sizeof(UNIVERSE) / 2`, there's still space left for us. (just don't want to wait until all is initialized near the border-case) :-)

Comment: I just will not start to discuss performance of realloc. The alternative will very likely be beyond the TO's skills (that is a statement, no offense).

Comment: I updated my code but 'buf' doesn't return anything when I try to puts/printf it.

Comment: And you should really learn how to use `realloc()` correctly.

Comment: Apologies, i forgot to add the trailing `'\0'` . Will edit now.

Comment: Ok, but I do will not discuss this (just had an argument on that). `realloc()` might have to copy, depending on heap fragmentation and OS optimizations, this might be avoidable mostly, but not completely. It also might add to fragmentation and if it copies, both areas have to be reserved in parallel. The alternative: linked list of arrays. Once the corrent block is full, chain the next. For systems without MMU, this is definitively superiour and for others likely (just choose the size of the array appropriately). ...

Comment: ... Tradeof: indexing is more difficult, but you might build an index table once finished filling. That still produces some overhead, but for many algorithms that will be negligible. For parallel algorithms that might allow to split the buffer per node, allowing to change CPU-association of the memory area (NUMA e.g.). On small embedded, that would be the structure of choice; these often do not support realloc, or even malloc&co as such.

Comment: Disclaimer (to ever reader of the above): I do not recomend that if you are just practicing and do not really know what a linked list is! But you might take this as a hint to learn about them - they are one of the most basic and most versatile data structures in programming.

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior.

You never set `string` to point anywhere, so you can't dereference that pointer.

You need something like:

```
char buf[1024] = "", *string = buf;
```

that initializes `string` to point to valid memory where you can write, and also sets that memory to an empty string so you can use `strcat()`.

Note that looping `strcat()` like this is very inefficient, since it needs to find the end of the destination string on each call. It's better to just use pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> char *string;

You've declared an uninitialised variable with this statement. With some compilers, in debug this may be initialised to 0. In other compilers and a release build, you have no idea what this is pointing to in memory. You may find that when you build and run in release, your program will crash, but appears to be ok in debug. The actual behaviour is undefined.

You need to either create a variable on the stack by doing something like this

```
char string[100]; // assuming you're not going to receive more than 99 characters (100 including the NULL terminator)
```

Or, on the heap: -

```
char string* = (char*)malloc(100);
```

In which case you'll need to free the character array when you're finished with it.

Assuming you don't know how many characters the user will type, I suggest you keep track in your loop, to ensure you don't try to concatenate beyond the memory you've allocated.

Alternatively, you could limit the number of characters that a user may enter.

```
const int MAX_CHARS = 100;

char string[MAX_CHARS + 1]; // +1 for Null terminator

int numChars = 0;
while(numChars < MAX_CHARS) && (c=getchar())!= EOF) 
{
    ...
    ++numChars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comments, you cannot avoid `malloc()` / `calloc()` and probably `realloc()` for a problem such as you have described, where your program does not know until run time how much memory it will need, and must not have any predetermined limit.  In addition to the memory management issues on which most of the discussion and answers have focused, however, your code has some additional issues, including:

- `getchar()` returns type `int`, and to correctly handle all possible inputs you must not convert that `int` to `char` before testing against EOF.  In fact, for maximum portability you need to take considerable care in converting to `char`, for if default `char` is signed, or if its representation has certain other allowed (but rare) properties, then the value returned by `getchar()` may exceed its maximum value, in which case direct conversion exhibits undefined behavior.  (In truth, though, this issue is often ignored, usually to no ill effect in practice.)
- **Never** pass a user-provided string to `printf()` as the format string.  It will not do what you want for some inputs, and it can be exploited as a security vulnerability.  If you want to just print a string verbatim then `fputs(string, stdout)` is a better choice, but you can also safely do `printf("%s", string)`.

Here's a way to approach your problem that addresses all of these issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main()
{
    char *string = malloc(INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
    size_t cap = INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
    size_t next = 0;
    int c;

    if (!string) {
        // allocation error
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (next + 1 >= cap) {
            /* insufficient space for another character plus a terminator */
            cap *= 2;
            string = realloc(string, cap);
            if (!string) {
                /* memory reallocation failure */
                /* memory was leaked, but it's ok because we're about to exit */
                return 1;
            }
        }

#if (CHAR_MAX != UCHAR_MAX)
        /* char is signed; ensure defined behavior for the upcoming conversion */
        if (c > CHAR_MAX) {
            c -= UCHAR_MAX;
#if ((CHAR_MAX != (UCHAR_MAX >> 1)) || (CHAR_MAX == (-1 * CHAR_MIN)))
            /* char's representation has more padding bits than unsigned
               char's, or it is represented as sign/magnitude or ones' complement */
            if (c < CHAR_MIN) {
                /* not representable as a char */
                return 1;
            }
#endif
        }
#endif

        string[next++] = (char) c;
    }
    string[next] = '\0';

    fputs(string, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```